# Why does calling `system` with indirect object give syntax error only with autodie

Tags: perl

Perl's `system` function allows an indirect object.  In that case, the
indirect object is the program to run, allowing `argv[0]` to be
different from the name of the executable.

So I can do

```
system {"echo"} qw(echo foo);
```

However, when I use `autodie`:

```
use autodie qw(:all);
system {"echo"} qw(echo foo);
```

I get

```
syntax error at - line 2, near "} qw(echo foo)"
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) operator has three syntax.

```
system LIST
system $SCALAR LIST
system BLOCK LIST
```

(None has anything to do with indirect method calls, or objects at all.)

`autodie` replaces the uses of the `system` operator with calls to a sub with the same name. Subs can provide the `system LIST` syntax and the `system BLOCK LIST` syntax (by using a prototpye), but not both.

```
$ perl -e'
   CORE::say defined(prototype("CORE::system"))
       ? "Syntax can be emulated by subs."
       : "Syntax can\x27t be emulated by subs."
'
Syntax can't be emulated by subs.
```

As such, the less commonly-used syntax of `system $SCALAR LIST` and `system BLOCK LIST` aren't available when autodie replaces `system`. This is [documented](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html#system%2fexec).

> Applying `autodie` to [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) or [`exec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) causes the exotic forms `system { $cmd } @args` or `exec { $cmd } @args` to be considered a syntax error until the end of the lexical scope. If you really need to use the exotic form, you can call `CORE::system` or `CORE::exec` instead, or use `no autodie qw(system exec)` before calling the exotic form.

Answer (score 4):

From the [autodie documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/autodie.html#system%2fexec):

> Applying `autodie` to `system` or `exec` causes the exotic forms `system { $cmd } @args` or `exec { $cmd } @args` to be considered a syntax error until the end of the lexical scope. If you really need to use the exotic form, you can call `CORE::system` or `CORE::exec` instead, or use `no autodie qw(system exec)` before calling the exotic form.

What you're seeing is exactly what's documented as what will happen.